# Terraform - Select GZIP compression option on an Azure Stream Analytics Input (Event Hub)

Tags: terraform, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics, terraform-provider-azure, stream-analytics

I need to set the Gzip compression option onto my EventHub input in a Stream Analytics job to get it to process.

The documentation doesn't have "Compression" options available in the SA job Event Hub Input specification.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/stream_analytics_stream_input_eventhub.html

[Screenshot from Azure SA Job input for the Event Hub with GZip compression selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaZKp.png)

Has anyone managed to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my understanding to the document of Terraform, since it doesn't have the "Compression" property, so it may not support managing the compression type of SA job Event Hub Input. Or you can have a try to add the "Compression" property after "serialization" property.

```
compression {    
    type = "GZip"
}
```

By the way, according to the [update rest api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/streamanalytics/stream-analytics-input#update) of stream-analytics-input, we can see it doesn't support update compression type. So I think it probably can not be implemented in Terraform too.

Comment: Hi, it is not explicitly stated, but the UPDATE operation in Azure Stream Analytics REST API supports all the fields that can be used at create time. Let me know if this works for you in Terraform.

Comment: Thanks both. I tried compression after the serialization, but returned with..."Error: Unsupported block type. Blocks of type "compression" are not expected here.". Such a shame, but to be honest though the Stream Analytics Jobs are poorly supported with IaC, I have found these really frustrating to put into a single code structure so far (avoiding ARM of course). For example, FunctionApp Outputs are not supported by TF or Azure CLI

Answer (score 0):

This is currently **still not** supported in tf `0.13.3` and azurerm `2.24.0`. It generates the following error:

> Error: Unsupported block type
>
> blocks of type "compression" are not expected here.

This might be supported in the future, but do not count on it.